# Using Legacy OpenGL and Modern OpenGL in same application

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a work laptop that only supports OpenGL 2.1 and i have desktop in my home with OpenGL 4.4. I'm working on a project in my Desktop. So i make my program that compatible with Modern OpenGL. But i want to develop this project in my work laptop. My question is can i make this project compatible with both Legacy and Modern OpenGL?

Like this.

```
#ifdef MODERN_OPENGL
some code..
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
...
glEnd();
#else
glGenBuffers(&vbo);
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

What you suggest is perfectly possible, however if you do it through preprocessor macros you're going to end up in conditional compilation hell. The best bet for your approach is to compile into shared libraries, one compiled for legacy and one for modern and load the right variant on demand. However when approaching it from that direction you can just as well ditch the preprocessor juggling and simply move render path variants into their own compilation units.

Another approach is to decide on what render path to use at runtime. This is my preferred approach and I usually implement it through a function pointer table (vtable). For example the volume rasterizer library I offer has full support for OpenGL-2.x and modern core profiles and will dynamically adjust its code paths *and* the shaders' GLSL code to match the capabilities of the OpenGL context it's being used in.

If you're worried about performance, keep in mind that literally every runtime environment that allows for polymorphic function overwriting has to go through that bottleneck. Yes, it does amount to some cost, but OTOH it's so common that modern CPUs' instruction prefetch and indirect jump circuitry has been optimized to deal with that.

---

#### EDIT: Important note about what "legacy" OpenGL is and what not

So here is something very important I forgot to write in the first place: Legacy OpenGL is not `glBegin`/`glEnd`. It's about having a fixed function pipeline by default and vertex arrays being *client* side.

Let me reiterate that: *Legacy OpenGL-1.1 and later **does have** vertex arrays!* What this effectively means is, that large amounts of code that are concerned with the layout and filling the content of vertex arrays will work for all of OpenGL. The differences are in how vertex array data is actually submitted to OpenGL.

In legacy, fixed function pipeline OpenGL you have a number of predefined attributes and function which you use to point OpenGL toward the memory regions holding the data for these attributes before making the `glDraw…` call.

When shaders were introduced (OpenGL-2.x, or via ARB extension earlier) they came along with the *very same* `glVertexAttribPointer` functions that are still in use with modern OpenGL. And in fact in OpenGL-2 you can still point them toward client side buffers.

OpenGL-3.3 core made the use of *buffer objects* mandatory. However buffer objects are also available for older OpenGL versions (core in OpenGL-1.5) or through an ARB extension; you can even use them for the non-programmable GPUs (which means effectively first generation Nvidia GeForce) of the past century.

The bottom line is: You can perfectly fine write code for OpenGL that's compatible with a huge range for version profiles and require only very little version specific code to manage the legacy/modern transistion.

Comment: "*However buffer objects are also available for legacy OpenGL (even down to the fixed function pipeline) through an ARB extension*" Buffer objects were core in GL 1.5. So if he's using 2.1, then he has access to them.

Comment: I have a working "legacy" application, and I have no idea how to port it to the "new" scheme.  Is there any guidance about this, or will my code simply stop working one day?  For the record, none of the information in these answers is any help - I just don't understand it or what I need to do.  My code is finished, and does not need or use shaders (whatever they may be), so "modern" opengl offers nothing but obsolescence to me, it would seem :(

Comment: @m4r35n357 as a very quick and easy test see if your application keeps working with GPUs made by AMD, or using the software fallback rasterizer of Mesa. If it does work with those, you're in the clear. Nvidia is notorious for giving far too much leeway, but the drivers of AMD and Mesa are super strict.  Don't worry, support for legacy OpenGL is not going to vanish anytime soon, there's just too much mission critical software out there that depends on it.

Comment: @datenwolf if true that is good news!  Reading on Khronos etc. they seem to say older features are "merely" deprecated, then on virtually the same page say they have actually been _removed_ in such-a-such version.

Comment: @m4r35n357 yes, features got removed from newer OpenGL versions. However these then are versions marked **core**, and a program will never be handed a *core profile* context, if it doesn't ask so explicitly. This is in fact specified, i.e. if no core version is requested, then either a *__compatibility__ profile* context is created, or a legacy context.

Comment: @m4r35n357 all the versioning details are not an issue for end users and entirely within the developers' realm of responsibilities.

Comment: @datenwolf yep, it is that confusing ;)  Although I don't count myself a software developer as such, I _am_ the author of the application in question,  and I still don't understand what you are saying!  Thanks for having a go though.  I shall just hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by writing your application using the "new" OpenGL 3/4 Core API, but restrict yourself to the subset that is supported in OpenGL 2.1. As datenwolf points out above, you have vertex attribute pointers and buffers even in 2.1

So no glBegin/End blocks, but also no matrix pushing/popping/loading, no pushing/popping attrib state, no lighting. Do everything in vertex and fragment shaders with uniforms.

Restricting yourself to 2.1 will be a bit more painful than using the cool new stuff in OpenGL 4, but not by much. In my experience switching away from the matrix stack and built-in lighting is the hardest part regardless of which version of OpenGL, and it's work you were going to have to do anyway.

At the end you'll have a single code version, and it will be easier to update if/when you decide to drop 2.1 support.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which utility library / extension loader you're using, you can check at runtime which version is supported by current context by checking `GLAD_GL_VERSION_X_X`, `glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR/MINOR)` etc., and create appropriate renderer.